# Coda Slider and Scroll Buttons

Tags: jquery, scroll, jquery-animate, slider, coda-slider

SO,

I'm creating a vertical slider based on the [Coda Slider](http://jqueryfordesigners.com/demo/coda-slider.html). Although my knowledge of Jquery is very limited, I've managed to get the slider all but set up, with one significant snafu: the .before and .after animations (controlled by "left" and "right," or, in this case, "up" and "down," aren't linked to the "up" and "down" DIVs I've added. I'd love for clicking the "up" div to cause the slider to roll up to the previous slide.

I'm still tinkering with the script, but I've got the feeling that given my lack of experience with Jquery, I might be at the mercy of SO to figure this one out.

Any ideas are GREATLY appreciated!

My **javascript** for the slider:

```
$(document).ready(function () {

var $panels = $('#slider .scrollContainer > div');
var $container = $('#slider .scrollContainer');

// if false, we'll float all the panels left and fix the width 
// of the container
var horizontal = false;

// float the panels left if we're going horizontal
if (horizontal) {
    $panels.css({
        'float' : 'left',
        'position' : 'relative' // IE fix to ensure overflow is hidden
    });

    // calculate a new width for the container (so it holds all panels)
    $container.css('width', $panels[0].offsetWidth * $panels.length);
}

// collect the scroll object, at the same time apply the hidden overflow
// to remove the default scrollbars that will appear
var $scroll = $('#slider .scroll').css('overflow', 'hidden');

// apply our left + right buttons
$scroll
    .before('<div id="uptopdiv" />')
    .after('<img class="scrollButtons right" src="images/scroll_right.png" />');

// handle nav selection
function selectNav() {
    $(this)
        .parents('ul:first')
            .find('a')
                .removeClass('selected')
            .end()
        .end()
        .addClass('selected');
}

$('#slider .navigation').find('a').click(selectNav);

// go find the navigation link that has this target and select the nav
function trigger(data) {
    var el = $('#slider .navigation').find('a[href$="' + data.id + '"]').get(0);
    selectNav.call(el);
}

if (window.location.hash) {
    trigger({ id : window.location.hash.substr(1) });
} else {
    $('ul.navigation a:first').click();
}

// offset is used to move to *exactly* the right place, since I'm using
// padding on my example, I need to subtract the amount of padding to
// the offset.  Try removing this to get a good idea of the effect
var offset = parseInt((horizontal ? 
    $container.css('paddingTop') : 
    $container.css('paddingLeft')) 
    || 0) * -1;


var scrollOptions = {
    target: $scroll, // the element that has the overflow

    // can be a selector which will be relative to the target
    items: $panels,

    navigation: '.navigation a',

    // selectors are NOT relative to document, i.e. make sure they're unique
    prev: 'img.left', 
    next: 'img.right',

    // allow the scroll effect to run both directions
    axis: 'xy',

    onAfter: trigger, // our final callback

    offset: offset,

    // duration of the sliding effect
    duration: 500,

    // easing - can be used with the easing plugin: 
    // http://gsgd.co.uk/sandbox/jquery/easing/
    easing: 'swing'
};

// apply serialScroll to the slider - we chose this plugin because it 
// supports// the indexed next and previous scroll along with hooking 
// in to our navigation.
$('#slider').serialScroll(scrollOptions);

// now apply localScroll to hook any other arbitrary links to trigger 
// the effect
$.localScroll(scrollOptions);

// finally, if the URL has a hash, move the slider in to position, 
// setting the duration to 1 because I don't want it to scroll in the
// very first page load.  We don't always need this, but it ensures
// the positioning is absolutely spot on when the pages loads.
scrollOptions.duration = 1;
$.localScroll.hash(scrollOptions);

});
```

**My HTML**:

```
<script src="http://www.marcatectura.com/wp-content/jquery-1.2.6.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.marcatectura.com/wp-content/jquery.scrollTo-1.3.3.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="http://www.marcatectura.com/wp-content/jquery.localscroll-1.2.5.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<script src="http://www.marcatectura.com/wp-content/jquery.serialScroll-1.2.1.js" type="text/javascript" charset="utf-8"></script>
<body>
<div id="wrapper">    
    <div id="intro">
        This area can house any content within the wrapper prior to the actual slider, but is best left empty for the Adrienne Adams feature.
    </div>
    <div class="scrollButtons left"></div>
    <div id="upbuttoncontainer"><div id="uptopdiv"><div id="uptoparrow-border-left"></div><div id="uptoparrow-border-right"></div><div id="uptoparrow-up-internal"></div><div id="uptoparrow-up"></div></div><div id="upbottomdiv"><div id="uparrow-border-left"></div><div id="uparrow-border-right"></div><div id="uparrow-up-internal"></div><div id="uparrow-up"></div></div></div>
    <div id="slider">    
       <div class="scroll">
            <div class="scrollContainer">
                <div class="panel" id="wib1">wib1 Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor<a href="#editor">Editor</a>incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</div>
            <div class="panel" id="files"><h2>Files</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div>
            <div class="panel" id="editor"><h2>Editor</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad <a href="#books">books</a> minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div>
            <div class="panel" id="preview"><h2>Preview</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div>
            <div class="panel" id="css"><h2>CSS</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div>
            <div class="panel" id="terminal"><h2>Terminal</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum. <a href="#sites">And some sites</a></p></div>
            <div class="panel" id="books"><h2>Books</h2><p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p></div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="shade"></div>
    </div>
 <div id="downbuttoncontainer"><div id="downtopdiv"><div id="downtoparrow-border-left"></div><div id="downtoparrow-border-right"></div><div id="downtoparrow-up-internal"></div><div id="downtoparrow-up"></div></div><div id="downbottomdiv"><div id="downarrow-border-left"></div><div id="downarrow-border-right"></div><div id="downarrow-up-internal"></div><div id="downarrow-up"></div></div></div>
    <p>AFTER slider text:<a href="#books">books</a> consectetur adipisicing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco <a href="#wib1">sites</a> laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure <a href="#terminal">terminal</a>  dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.</p>

</div>
```

​

-Marcatectura

Comment: Since SO wouldn't let me post a link to JsFiddle in the question, here it is: http://jsfiddle.net/Koubenec/f8XFW/18/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured out how to achieve the same effect using a less complicated script:

```
$(function() {
var y=0;
$(".down").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#container").animate({scrollTop: y+=250}, 500);
})
$(".up").click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    $("#container").animate({scrollTop: y-=250}, 500);
})        
})
```

The JsFiddle is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/Koubenec/ynzPz/9/).